# Звук и преобразование фурье

Tags: c++, аудио, фурье

У меня есть некий звук с микрофона.
Частота дискретизации 44100.
Его я поделил на фрагменты по 2048 и загрузил в динамики.
В итоге получилось прослушивание того что в микрофоне.

Далее над каждым фрагментом сделал FFT и обнулил некоторые частоты.
После этого появились странные звуки.
Звуки появляются явно из-за краёв участков по 2048.

Как эти звуки устранять? 
Есть ли непрерывный вариант для фурье?
Как ещё можно получить информацию о звуке кроме FFT?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Оконное_преобразование_Фурье и возьмите, например, окно Хэмминга

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непрерывный вариант обычно делается с перекрытиями. Каждый следующий фрагмент берётся не с конца предыдущего, а с середины, затем на фрагменты накладывается окно, если не знаете какое лучше возьмите Hann window. Если такие фрагменты сложить во временной области то получится исходный сигнал.

Вообще над произвольным фрагментом сигнала делать FFT обычно не хорошо, так как преобразование делается над бесконечными сигналом составленным из данного фрагмента и когда случайное начало соединяется со случайным концом, то получается довольно широкополосный стук

В качестве хорошего примера можете почитать про MP3 сжатие